Algorithm of projecting nurbs/curves on to cylinder and sphere
I am looking for the algorithm to project nurbs（or other curves）onto cylinder and sphere?related books or articles will also help, thanks!!
I find some method like first project start point onto the surface and discrete the curve into polyline, use iteration method to project many discrete point onto surface and approximate a curve on the target surface.
I am wondering if there is some analytical method for certain question? like project nurbs onto cylinder or project nurbs onto sphere?
by the way, project direction is along normal.
I also want to ask how to evaluate the quality of projection? will Hausdorff distance work?

There might be more special interest overflow communities to ask this.
Is this pure geometry related or you are interested on 3D rendering aspects. Not clear
